# How to reset In.read() after going through a loop != '\n'

Tags: java, char

How can I reset the input in a char text after setting it to enter in the while loop. After going through the while loop it should start again from the beginning.
For example

```
char text = In.read();
```

Lets say I typed `asdf`

```
while(text != '\n' ) { 
  text = In.read();
}


//here is text = enter
```

but I want it to be at 'a' again from asdf.

Here is what I got so far

```
System.out.print("Please enter your text ");
    char text = In.read();

// some other code here
//...

for (int i = 0; i < textcount.length ; i++)
        {
            j = 0;
            while(text != '\n' )
            {

                int a = Character.getNumericValue(textcount[i]);
                int b = Character.getNumericValue(text);


                if(a == b)
                {
                    j++;
                    charCounts[i] = j;
                }
                text = In.read();
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I fixed it. I just change it so that the while loop comes before the for loop.
Now it's working without reseting anything.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what kind of stream `In` is.

- If it is a `ByteArrayInputStream` or similar you can call `reset()` to reset to the previous "mark" position.  For a `ByteArrayInputStream`, that position defaults to the start of the stream; see [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html).
- If it is a `FileInputStream` you may be able to use `mark` and `reset`, though it may depend on the OS and the way that the stream was created.  (The javadoc doesn't say, one way or the other.)

  In your case I suspect that you will be reading from `FileInputStream` that wraps either a pipe or a device file that is *not* rewindable.
- If it is a `SocketInputStream`, `mark` and `reset` are unlikely to work.  Rewinding of streams coming from a remote server is not possible.  Network transfer protocols (and servers) don't support that kind of thing.
- If it is a `BufferedInputStream`, `mark` and `reset` may work, depending on the size of the buffer.  Read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedInputStream.html) to understand the relationship between the buffer size and mark / reset.

---

So what is the solution in your case?

- Mark / reset probably won't work on `In`.
- You could wrap `In` in a `BufferedInputStream` with a large enough buffer, though predicting how large it needs to be is problematic (at least in theory!)
- The best solution is probably to change your code so that you don't need to reread the input.  For example:

  - save the characters that you read in an array,
  - use `BufferedReader::readLine` or a `Scanner::nextLine` to read the input from the user a line at a time.

Comment: Thank you but is there no other way only using In.read() without using any arrays strings or other methods ? What if I change the loop so that my while loop comes before my for loop. Hmm..

Comment: 1) I think I already answered that. 2) You haven't provided enough code or description for me to understand what you mean by *"What if I change the loop so that my while loop comes before my for loop."*   The problem (for me) is that your code doesn't make a lot of sense to me.  I can't work out what it is actually supposed to do.